# Listar contenido de git

Tags: c#, git

Listar el contenido de https://github.com/half-ogre/qed/tree/master/qed con C# en una consola.

Por ejemplo el siguiente código muestra los seguidores de un usuario y la cantidad de repositorios de un usuario, pero necesito listar el contenido de la dirección anterior.

```
public async Task<String> TestGitHub() {

        var github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("MyAmazingApp"));

        var user = await github.User.Get("half-ogre");

        Console.WriteLine(user.Followers +" folks  love the half ogre!");

        Console.WriteLine("Repositories: \n"+ user.PublicRepos);

        return user.Url;
    }
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con la descripción de los errores y explica mejor el problema que tienes con este código. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo usas esta libreria

[octokit.net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net)

si es asi lo primero que recomendaria es que analices el codigo de los test para entender como usar la libreria.

Tienes una buena documentacion

[Octokit.net Documentation](http://octokitnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/issues/)

Pero para listar contenido debes evaluar la propiedad `Repository`

```
var github = new GitHubClient(...); 

var contents = await github
            .Repository
            .Content
            .GetAllContents("octokit", "octokit.net");
```

[Getting all files for repository using OctoKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023902/getting-all-files-for-repository-using-octokit)